# Scraping with BeautifulSoup to extract data from a bike race

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract times from a race:
[https://www.datasport.com/live/ranking/?lang=en&racenr=23466#1_5584A2][1]

What I found so far by inspecting the HTML code is, that each row in the table is within a `<tr class="Hover LastRecordLine" style="cursor: pointer;">` tag. Furthermore, all individual times have the following in common:

`<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">5:05:20</td>`

Where the individual time, e.g. *h:min:sec* differs.
I want to collect these times in an array using **Python BeautifulSoup**. Any help is highly appreciated
[1]: https://www.datasport.com/live/ranking/?lang=en&racenr=23466#1_5584A2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is generating from api_calls json response

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
data=[]
params = {
    "eventid": "162106",
    "key": "fc9013ff4607be8febcb87f3390c2b4b",
    "listname": "Result Lists|1 Classement L-L",
    "page": "results",
    "contest": "1",
    "r": "all",
    "l": "0"}
api_url = "https://my3.raceresult.com/RRPublish/data/list.php"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers =headers)
for item in r.json()['data']['#1_VELO DE ROUTE']:
    data.append(item[11])
    
           
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['6:18:32', '5:56:04', '6:15:09', '6:37:47', '7:11:51', '5:05:20', '7:26:44', '5:59:34', '5:33:22', '5:34:34', '4:33:21', '5:58:20', '5:57:40', '5:10:27', '5:42:41', '6:03:54', '5:43:39', '5:25:56', '7:03:39', '8:01:29', '5:08:00', '4:40:23', '4:29:23', '5:14:23', '6:17:59', '6:18:12', '8:22:17', '4:27:40', '6:48:40', '7:17:38', '6:31:14', '5:07:32', '4:47:50', '5:32:09', '5:37:50', '9:10:30', '6:14:39', '5:31:43', '5:13:49', '7:55:15', '5:16:55', '7:02:14', '5:22:31', '6:51:40', '5:25:18', '5:59:38', '4:54:29', '7:28:49', '5:20:50', '5:33:21', '6:30:50', '7:21:05', '5:54:09', '5:43:15', '6:51:57', '5:17:52', '', '6:33:13', '5:40:03', '6:16:23', '6:14:10', '5:58:50', '4:48:06', '5:27:59', '4:56:21', '', '6:48:39', '6:05:42', '6:40:30', '4:30:52', '6:56:53', '5:39:03', '4:54:29', '4:48:46', '4:22:39', '', '4:52:27', '6:54:44', '6:10:37', '7:21:37', '6:23:59', '7:10:35', '7:48:33', '6:03:02', '7:06:43', '5:23:14', '8:21:11', '5:35:39', '6:00:23', '6:56:55', '5:00:35', '5:40:31', '5:59:19', '5:51:05', '7:37:01', '7:06:33', '5:15:20', '6:22:26', '6:04:30', '4:49:23', '8:13:22', '7:01:43', '5:16:01', '5:18:52', '5:44:38', '4:29:02', '5:11:21', '7:42:03', '7:07:36', '', '5:17:03', '6:54:21', '5:13:12', '7:01:38', '7:37:28', '7:47:16', '5:45:02', '6:04:03', '6:06:11', '7:14:12', '6:49:12', '7:46:21', '7:19:10', '7:19:09', '7:06:12', '5:20:51', '5:48:18', '6:37:34', '6:10:50', '5:30:35', '6:03:39', '6:03:36', '6:17:37', '5:32:13', '5:32:10', '4:57:49', '4:50:08', '5:28:26', '7:18:45', '', '5:46:58', '6:39:33', '4:54:53', '4:33:58', '5:45:30', '5:02:32', '7:16:40', '6:17:52', '7:36:58', '6:56:37', '5:37:49', '6:18:42', '6:18:41', '6:47:20', '', '5:41:04', '5:41:04', '4:51:37', '5:15:32', '6:13:02', '7:50:11', '5:55:34', '7:50:48', '4:47:47', '4:58:22', '6:43:42', '6:39:38', '4:53:32', '5:59:18', '7:26:01', '7:08:25', '7:00:14', '5:44:47', '6:06:52', '5:52:24', '6:39:30', '4:51:07', '7:06:46', '6:02:52', '6:06:20', '4:47:47', '4:51:10', '5:02:56', '5:44:42', '6:24:00', '6:23:14', '6:44:23', '6:01:57', '6:36:17', '6:12:07', '5:37:10', '5:02:27', '5:37:28', '5:52:43', '4:52:08', '', '5:28:22', '6:03:48', '6:17:37', '4:58:14', '', '6:21:34', '5:38:40', '4:24:11', '6:42:18', '6:28:13', '8:00:44', '7:33:00', '7:45:03', '5:32:49', '6:38:58', '5:52:24', '5:48:17', '7:55:18', '5:48:00', '7:13:59', '7:39:03', '5:18:17', '6:29:20', '5:24:12', '6:43:15', '4:55:26', '6:57:41', '5:42:30', '6:13:13', '6:57:04', '5:59:58', '8:57:05', '6:46:01', '4:59:46', '7:21:56', '5:29:05', '7:08:24', '5:41:26', '6:25:50', '5:04:59', '6:01:20', '5:53:38', '6:31:32', '6:14:33', '6:16:20', '5:25:59', '6:54:10', '8:45:40', '6:43:27', '6:41:46', '4:50:14', '5:46:50', '6:46:11', '7:39:50', '5:03:03', '5:28:53', '6:17:09', '8:04:27', '6:09:52', '5:31:50', '6:36:47', '6:00:01', '6:56:46', '5:47:33', '', '5:03:10', '4:51:37', '6:21:05', '6:00:32', '5:33:36', '6:00:28', '4:52:29', '8:43:33', '6:10:32', '7:26:56', '4:42:49', '6:07:18', '4:51:18', '4:48:50', '5:44:37', '4:34:33', '6:53:08', '6:53:07', '6:10:37', '4:46:23', '5:24:15', '6:10:16', '4:31:55', '8:04:13', '5:10:52', '5:21:28', '6:12:20', '', '6:47:49', '6:11:06', '6:06:22', '', '5:09:41', '6:57:49', '7:10:23', '5:44:52', '7:55:18', '7:52:00', '6:04:57', '8:04:13', '7:05:58', '7:32:30', '7:30:26', '6:52:32', '6:10:59', '5:13:06', '5:10:30', '5:14:14', '6:39:19', '4:23:34', '7:15:42', '6:21:29', '5:56:44', '6:20:29', '8:46:31', '5:13:56', '4:30:54', '', '6:27:47', '5:45:33', '4:41:37', '5:14:42', '7:18:49', '6:35:54', '6:00:57', '5:46:02', '5:46:02', '6:55:55', '4:50:14', '7:23:49', '5:06:11', '6:46:02', '6:38:37', '4:40:41', '5:24:35', '5:16:46', '4:43:43', '6:45:01', '6:22:17', '5:56:17', '5:49:27', '5:25:17', '6:34:32', '6:34:33', '7:58:12', '6:35:58', '7:17:03', '5:47:52', '5:50:52', '6:40:41', '7:14:25', '7:05:21', '5:08:40', '4:48:50', '4:28:35', '6:05:42', '8:29:46', '6:01:08', '4:58:38', '6:51:40', '7:18:42', '4:23:49', '7:14:35', '5:45:19', '5:39:01', '4:57:23', '5:43:57', '7:26:44', '6:12:13', '8:11:21', '4:45:56', '7:01:00', '5:50:17', '6:26:14', '5:51:12', '7:21:56', '6:18:43', '6:18:52', '6:35:46', '5:23:50', '6:22:17', '4:34:59', '7:45:38', '6:51:20', '4:54:01', '7:30:39', '7:00:32', 
'', '8:57:03', '5:56:35', '7:45:27', '6:55:06', '5:46:06', '6:33:27', '6:20:57', '6:49:47', '7:04:04', '8:12:35', '5:57:32', '6:46:37', '6:09:55', '4:40:45', '5:29:51', '6:31:04', '7:41:18', '6:24:59', '4:57:45', '8:09:32', '5:50:12', '6:39:39', '6:09:48', '6:36:49', '5:31:36', 
'4:56:15', '5:17:34', '4:47:19', '5:20:10', '5:50:09', '6:24:07', '5:43:39', '6:35:05', '5:39:36', '', '6:37:44', '6:11:39', '6:19:06', '8:14:06', '6:46:35', '4:55:49', '4:45:22', '6:26:04', '6:51:33', '5:18:04', '5:57:28', '4:34:03', '6:07:53', '5:19:01', '8:04:10', '6:33:53', 
'5:52:47', '4:47:55', '5:57:23', '8:45:41', '6:12:54', '5:49:28', '6:43:56', '6:36:09', '5:11:58', '6:17:59', '5:54:54', '5:52:40', '6:56:51', '4:45:19', '6:05:43', '6:18:05', '6:38:04', '5:21:04', '6:12:42', '6:21:24', '5:17:52', '', '6:35:56', '5:52:22', '6:54:19', '8:14:02', 
'4:32:57', '5:14:44', '5:34:21', '5:41:06', '6:59:21', '4:44:44', '8:50:24', '6:28:56', '5:54:33', '5:05:57', '6:29:40', '6:21:15', '7:28:45', '5:18:16', '7:36:57', '7:36:57', '6:52:05', '5:32:13', '5:08:32', '7:07:26', '4:45:07', '8:13:05', '6:04:31', '5:31:54', '6:19:43', '5:02:14', '5:02:14', '5:56:38', '5:43:01', '5:08:53', '4:28:43', '5:33:14', '5:36:25', '7:04:37', '7:18:45', '5:06:30', '5:52:48', '7:30:45', '', '6:54:52', '4:28:46', '6:25:53', '5:50:14', '5:51:05', '7:18:53', '6:08:59', '5:22:51', '7:16:03', '4:55:28', '6:20:30', '5:13:16', '4:41:34', '4:41:35', '7:46:53', '4:52:54', '4:41:34', '6:12:17', '6:37:51', '6:56:04', '6:21:27', '6:21:43', '6:35:27', '5:08:04', '5:52:00', '6:20:28', '6:44:46', '5:37:10', '6:47:35', '6:36:53', '6:47:37', '5:12:35', '7:14:37', '6:31:04', '5:32:35', '6:44:52', '6:44:49', '5:53:46', '5:53:47', '6:05:12', '6:05:11', '6:10:02', '6:12:41', '', '7:19:01', '7:07:25', '7:07:19', '6:20:35', '5:52:11', '5:52:11', '', '6:55:54', '6:28:49', '5:19:07', '6:41:11', '6:54:22', '6:37:43', '6:06:41', '5:24:47', '5:56:00', '5:09:40', '5:28:15', '6:47:22', '5:47:33', '6:57:35', '5:40:44', '5:56:15', '6:53:36', '5:01:07', '4:37:16', '7:32:53', '5:40:18', '4:28:17', '7:21:39', '6:01:33', '5:15:58', '4:44:46', '', '5:45:54', '5:58:53', '6:47:53', '7:04:56', '8:18:52', '6:03:50', '6:18:52', '7:42:32', '7:42:34', '6:57:28', '6:47:37', '7:01:21', '5:58:12', '5:11:07', '5:05:52', '5:07:05', '7:07:02', '6:47:39', '6:06:13', '5:26:06', '7:05:19', '6:14:13', '5:31:56', '4:22:23', '5:27:58', '7:31:45', '6:15:02', '7:18:03', '7:04:38', '5:57:07', '5:26:16', '6:17:27', '6:00:50', '4:45:44', '7:56:20', '6:20:34', '6:48:02', '7:01:07', '5:16:15', '5:16:15', '6:35:51', '6:12:16', '5:17:30', '6:09:28', '5:24:45', '7:33:03', '5:28:07', '6:47:33', '6:04:25', '6:08:41', '6:19:22', '5:53:11', '8:05:28', '', '5:12:11', '7:33:45', '5:58:44', '6:52:59', '5:50:12', '6:49:14', '5:55:00', '6:07:53', '6:05:38', '5:44:59', '6:07:15', '5:48:47', '5:04:03', '4:51:35', '6:24:05', '6:07:17', '6:03:52', '6:03:59', '5:50:07', '6:41:25', '6:21:17', '6:44:19', '6:28:28', '4:47:57', '6:14:08', '5:38:03', '7:04:58', '5:09:03', '6:47:47', '6:32:55', '6:33:04', '4:21:34', '5:53:54', '5:55:13', '5:58:55', '6:31:36', '7:36:55', '5:54:57', '5:58:48', '5:31:31', '4:45:52', '5:00:35', '7:30:44', '6:00:31', '5:41:30', '7:59:03', '4:40:28', '7:07:48', '8:09:36', '7:21:39', '4:36:00', '7:26:41', 
'6:12:45', '4:40:51', '6:18:10', '6:42:32', '4:29:23', '6:47:47', '6:33:31', '5:11:16', '4:51:43', '5:23:52', '4:47:43', '6:37:48', '5:39:28', '6:23:31', '6:19:20', '6:54:22', '6:54:23', '8:58:11', '5:59:11', '5:38:24', '7:10:25', '6:22:09', '4:55:35', '6:04:24', '4:41:41', '6:14:10', '4:55:43', '5:25:46', '6:58:39', '7:48:35', '6:28:12', '5:30:37', '6:52:46', '', '7:04:20', '7:33:25', '6:56:52', '4:53:34', '6:56:51', '5:11:02', '4:47:04', '6:16:44', '4:44:55', '4:42:01', '6:09:13', '6:54:55', '7:23:34', '6:41:45', '6:41:45', '7:14:20', '5:26:53', '6:36:02', '7:05:59', '6:57:58', '6:17:31', '6:02:59', '4:47:45', '4:49:31', '6:18:17', '6:22:38', '6:30:48', '6:50:45', '6:17:39', '6:15:08', '6:40:41', '4:27:18', '7:54:14', '7:54:13', '5:21:31', '5:59:58', '7:18:03', '7:18:02', '6:26:21', '5:08:03', '4:51:47', '5:28:20', '5:54:11', '6:25:44', '6:32:42', '4:49:01', '7:14:26', '7:04:32', '6:01:06', '6:28:57', '4:22:39', '5:57:28', '6:19:46', '5:46:29', '', '6:47:52', '6:01:30', '4:52:58', '4:50:34', '5:43:14', '6:45:43', '5:41:56', '8:10:46', '6:32:44', '6:32:45', '4:56:52', '4:27:17', '4:42:11', '5:25:56', '4:41:37', '7:34:31', '6:13:33', '7:46:18', '6:03:07', '5:53:12', '6:06:43', '4:50:48', '4:57:01', '7:14:49', '6:54:23', '5:23:54', '7:07:20', '6:44:21', '6:31:12', '5:10:53', '6:33:29', '4:48:43', '6:28:30', '7:48:51', '5:01:51', '6:54:12', '7:08:25', '4:41:00', '5:27:23', '4:28:29', '4:44:32', '5:47:33', '5:44:55', '9:00:29', '4:58:03', '4:47:52', '6:36:10', '5:47:30', '6:59:36', '4:36:23', '4:38:26', '6:01:58', '7:17:04', '5:24:51', '5:50:02', '6:25:33', 
'6:12:52', '6:43:40', '7:02:58', '5:24:17', '5:27:56', '6:07:37', '6:44:45', '8:59:58', '9:00:01', '5:56:01', '5:56:23', '7:21:11', '5:15:58', '', '7:39:01', '5:29:39', '6:48:03', '4:57:41', '6:51:31', '8:03:19', '5:28:21', '5:28:21', '4:45:05', '6:29:47', '8:24:40', '6:35:55', 
'8:11:51', '7:20:19', '7:02:37', '6:44:23', '4:59:00', '7:05:58', '7:21:59', '5:14:44', '6:16:11', '6:33:19', '6:54:48', '5:54:29', '5:19:34', '6:52:36', '5:06:57', '5:06:56', '6:24:59', '7:40:43', '6:45:19', '8:13:04', '5:16:14', '5:41:14', '5:28:14', '5:08:10', '8:09:38', '6:55:34', '6:14:11', '6:33:35', '6:39:24', '7:14:55', '4:56:32', '6:49:54', '4:35:25', '5:17:43', '5:01:45', '7:34:33', '7:40:44', '5:59:59', '4:47:45', '5:48:58', '5:51:14', '5:16:31', '5:23:57', '8:15:17', '7:49:35', '6:19:06', '4:40:57', '5:13:42', '6:57:42', '6:00:53', '6:48:02', '6:01:17', '6:10:09', '7:42:09', '5:51:38', '7:01:45', '7:01:51', '5:27:33', '6:50:40', '6:44:54', '6:27:14', '6:03:07', '6:43:02', '8:04:31', '4:33:38', '6:14:10', '7:18:40', '5:15:21', '5:38:12', '7:45:43', '5:01:42', '5:39:02', '4:51:55', '5:24:54', '5:13:55', '5:18:08', '5:37:11', '7:04:29', '7:27:29', '7:26:29', '6:19:06', '5:48:49', '6:38:43', '5:14:46', '8:50:11', '5:43:32', '5:25:06', '6:14:34', '6:10:19', '7:21:24', '5:38:22', '6:12:33', '4:41:28', 
'5:12:59', '6:59:49', '6:44:49', '5:16:52', '7:49:34', '4:48:47', '5:52:41', '5:02:16', '5:45:56', '5:21:13', '4:43:17', '5:50:24', '5:41:42', '6:45:38', '5:40:46', '5:41:17', '6:34:04', '7:04:26', '7:46:19', '5:09:03', '6:12:30', '6:36:18', '8:25:34', '5:50:08', '5:55:57', '7:04:17', '6:19:05', '5:25:22', '6:24:02', '6:13:29', '6:14:15', '6:13:00', '6:06:04', '5:14:12', '7:46:18', '5:17:15', '7:26:00', '5:52:12', '5:54:03', '6:18:27', '5:04:39', '7:05:58', '7:17:34', '5:09:41', '7:47:46', '6:53:59', '5:44:53', '8:28:01', '7:13:01', '6:23:01', '5:49:03', '6:09:59', '5:09:38', '7:15:36', '6:12:06', '6:01:20', '5:49:27', '', '4:28:15', '5:14:41', '5:47:06', '7:27:27', '6:00:48', '5:02:36', '6:20:52', '7:26:43', '7:55:12', '6:47:51', '7:07:32', '6:53:34', '6:12:19', '7:04:24', '5:14:19', '5:14:15', '7:09:09', '6:21:09', '6:07:32', '6:58:42', '6:10:33', '5:54:39', '4:36:17', '6:15:28', '6:08:46', '6:28:04', '7:43:48', '5:29:03', '5:11:02', '4:42:20', '4:58:12', '6:34:09', '7:48:23', '6:53:02', '7:38:24', '6:51:24', '4:51:37', '7:01:31', '6:00:36', '8:00:41', '6:02:53', '6:52:20', '6:37:00', '8:23:48', '5:39:58', '6:28:25', '4:52:15', '7:26:21', '5:04:39', '7:24:19', '7:18:00', '6:02:13', '6:02:20', '6:20:50', '6:33:29', '5:37:12', '4:40:13', '7:15:49', '6:01:06', '6:37:00', '6:36:58', 
'4:50:54', '7:02:52', '6:23:45', '5:30:04', '5:17:25', '7:15:02', '6:20:32', '8:16:25', '5:14:09', '5:59:47', '8:00:42', '6:10:01', '7:28:05', '6:37:59', '6:28:28', '4:51:39', '6:28:02', '9:05:28', '5:04:00', '7:24:19', '5:23:32', '5:18:48', '5:37:55', '5:24:39', '5:24:38', '5:08:49', '5:23:48', '4:47:46', '4:24:23', '4:42:21', '5:30:23', '6:30:46', '6:54:52', '4:58:48', '4:50:13', '6:19:46', '7:08:54', '8:42:44', '5:18:34', '5:12:03', '6:33:28', '4:53:27', '5:28:07', '4:55:27', '6:56:45', '6:07:04', '7:35:45', '7:35:49', '6:28:26', '5:40:31', '7:18:42', '4:50:28', '5:37:49', '8:02:54', '5:12:59', '6:12:10', '6:25:33', '', '6:16:03', '6:01:08', '5:46:12', '8:50:17', '7:21:13', '5:51:04', '8:50:15', '5:25:51', '8:09:35', '7:07:02', '7:07:03', '4:45:55', '5:03:25', '5:34:10', '5:31:20', '5:53:13', '5:49:49', '4:51:10', '6:56:44', '6:17:25', '5:17:42', '6:04:45', '5:50:24', '5:59:31', '7:17:44', '5:59:17', '7:01:48', '6:47:35', '5:58:45', '7:21:58', '6:33:30', '5:11:40', '6:36:57', '5:58:23', '7:05:20', '6:56:52', '5:19:58', '5:24:43', '6:25:43', '6:17:13', '5:20:04', '6:23:45', '6:42:55', '7:18:44', '5:14:14', '7:10:58', '7:50:10', '6:10:25', '6:12:40', '4:58:15', '8:45:43', '6:29:09', '6:29:08', '7:30:45', '7:18:39', '6:26:15', '5:20:01', '5:58:07', '7:21:35', '7:35:36', '4:55:32', 
'6:22:16', '4:56:56', '5:07:58', '5:11:38', '8:21:59', '6:39:44', '7:23:35', '4:50:08', '5:58:12', '7:28:44', '5:06:11', '4:50:17', '5:41:39', '6:02:20', '4:32:19', '6:30:23', '7:36:58', '6:48:52', '6:14:16', '6:44:58', '5:57:30', '6:39:42', '6:39:39', '6:41:39', '5:24:54', '6:55:14', '6:31:03', '6:10:56', '5:40:13', '6:00:01', '4:23:29', '6:09:59', '7:30:40', '6:31:23', '7:22:17', '8:19:41', '4:29:22', '5:08:29', '5:26:07', '6:54:56', '6:21:17', '5:52:25', '5:36:43', '4:35:17', '6:02:53', '5:21:35', '5:19:08', '6:54:10', '6:35:59', '6:33:59', '4:45:41', '6:04:58', '6:04:56', '4:31:42', '6:23:03', '5:49:28', '7:09:07', '6:21:31', '7:40:27', '5:55:12', '6:18:11', '', '5:54:55', '6:42:52', '6:10:34', '5:20:42', '5:26:13', '7:31:13', '4:55:54', '6:29:34', '4:33:00', '5:50:01', '5:47:26', '7:14:24', '7:33:25', '5:15:42', '8:52:41', '6:56:35', '6:56:32', '7:20:23', '5:10:22', '7:43:46', '5:14:35', '6:05:09', '7:01:49', '5:19:18', '7:07:24', '7:37:26', '5:34:47', '6:12:41', '6:06:19', '6:06:53', '7:21:38', '5:00:10', '5:25:54', '4:53:01', '6:42:49', '5:07:32', '4:47:46', '6:26:20', '5:03:07', '6:47:20', '7:04:16', '6:43:03', '4:58:18', '4:31:01', '7:14:39', '4:34:50', '6:22:18', '5:46:23', '6:49:18', '7:33:52', '5:34:13', '3:03:21', '7:24:56', '6:09:36', '6:46:51', '4:45:33', '5:26:29', 
'5:26:28', '7:13:59', '7:52:03', '6:13:19', '5:36:26', '6:25:35', '8:24:39', '5:24:15', '6:32:09', '7:01:03', '', '9:28:41', '5:07:57', '5:40:22', '7:07:49', '5:44:56', '5:57:29', '5:38:56', '4:51:42', '5:00:54', '4:35:31', '6:37:48', '4:27:53', '5:21:52', '5:53:55', '6:56:53', 
'5:07:57', '6:18:42', '6:47:37', '5:29:02', '4:47:49', '5:29:17', '6:07:32', '5:01:59', '5:22:50', '8:04:06', '6:04:03', '6:52:14', '5:55:12', '5:23:27', '6:17:55', '6:40:46', '6:40:44', '7:46:53', '6:24:32', '6:19:30', '6:23:45', '5:08:00', '6:44:06', '6:57:53', '7:09:15', '6:14:01', '5:48:52', '4:45:10', '6:09:56', '6:38:39', '7:23:10', '4:45:09', '4:47:50', '7:17:27', '6:33:38', '5:33:02', '6:14:01', '6:25:07', '8:14:08', '5:03:23', '6:08:36', '6:11:24', '5:22:09', '6:41:28', '5:52:49', '8:08:52', '5:59:11', '7:18:11', '6:01:27', '6:51:44', '6:09:51', '4:43:23', '6:50:06', '8:52:42', '7:46:01', '5:25:31', '6:22:59', '5:14:42', '5:13:27', '7:23:29', '6:35:32', '8:09:33', '6:11:52', '7:04:49', '7:12:36', '7:41:02', '6:06:21', '6:06:19', '6:53:53', '5:29:25', '5:17:37', '6:06:06', '6:55:11', '8:04:35', '6:08:10', '5:07:59', '4:45:09', '4:55:35', '6:54:53', '6:16:03', '5:03:41', '5:05:14', '7:10:35', '6:02:34', '4:37:01', '5:19:51', '5:22:48', '4:47:47', '5:48:58', '6:56:46', '5:46:07', '6:55:49', '6:55:47', 
'6:08:45', '7:21:59', '6:43:12', '7:41:16', '6:30:48', '7:45:04', '5:32:07', '5:40:41', '7:41:19', '5:08:19', '5:43:41', '5:05:45', '7:32:00', '6:31:53', '4:54:38', '7:49:31', '4:50:34', '6:03:28', '6:05:47', '4:40:10', '6:34:01', '7:17:27', '8:09:06', '5:32:33', '5:43:34', '7:14:43', '4:58:55', '5:33:54', '6:39:06', '6:03:39', '5:22:51', '5:11:05', '5:10:12', '5:58:38', '', '7:46:55', '7:37:18', '', '5:37:01', '5:58:19', '6:45:41', '6:41:45', '7:19:59', '6:00:23', '7:46:03', '7:46:01', '7:46:02', '4:48:44', '5:30:21', '6:16:07', '5:44:42', '6:56:48', 
'7:09:19', '5:51:15', '', '7:21:39', '6:35:20', '5:06:08', '5:40:39', '6:36:55', '5:17:34', '6:26:10', '7:21:56', '6:31:58', '6:47:55', '6:15:04', '5:44:41', '4:50:33', '6:57:11', '5:21:57', '7:32:04', '5:13:20', '4:47:23', '5:47:15', '5:40:58', '5:48:14', '5:00:46', '6:13:05', 
'', '7:52:47', '7:52:50', '6:20:21', '7:07:27', '7:07:12', '7:33:19', '7:38:08', '7:05:55', '6:04:36', '6:36:00', '6:04:37', '7:22:14', '7:22:11', '7:21:58', '5:47:35', '6:00:03', '5:52:27', '7:21:56', '5:40:44', '7:06:16', '5:34:55', '4:33:53', '7:44:55', '5:58:30', '5:05:03', 
'9:10:24', '7:38:07', '7:09:34', '4:45:56', '6:57:53', '5:01:27', '4:32:27', '5:52:10', '8:22:38', '4:48:06', '6:19:14', '5:52:12', '6:40:13', '5:25:26', '6:03:29', '4:51:44', '7:28:46', '7:26:59', '5:56:41', '6:15:34', '5:53:44', '6:56:47', '6:35:01', '6:24:10', '6:22:17', '8:03:14', '8:03:12', '4:33:04', '6:22:18', '6:51:57', '6:21:23', '7:12:56', '7:12:56', '', '7:07:09', '5:53:25', '5:01:48', '5:29:42', '4:30:01', '8:10:17', '8:21:50', '8:21:53', '4:40:19', '7:03:40', '6:11:32', '5:50:01', '6:58:42', '6:56:45', '6:24:01', '6:45:42', '6:29:24', '8:16:24', '6:33:32', '5:39:09', '5:41:57', '6:12:26', '6:00:00', '6:25:56', '4:40:21', '6:15:12', '5:04:39', '5:21:53', '7:07:23', '6:54:43', '6:17:56', '4:47:47', '7:02:52', '7:59:54', '6:49:46', '6:49:46', '6:11:55', '4:47:47', '5:46:04', '5:03:41', '6:59:53', '4:45:44', '6:12:42', '5:24:41', '5:50:33', '6:24:37', '5:14:07', '5:01:49', '4:49:23', '6:42:55', '5:25:36', '6:44:29', '6:43:16', '6:05:05', '6:55:07', '5:59:35', '7:46:21', '6:49:01', '6:28:10', '4:33:51', '5:05:46', '6:14:49', '7:25:54', '6:03:53', '6:04:45', '6:50:19', '5:53:00', '', '4:42:00', '6:01:44', '5:46:50', '5:37:35', '6:39:20', '', '6:42:31', '7:34:44', '7:27:02', '7:05:38', '', '4:28:36', '5:00:29', '5:37:27', '6:48:46', '7:23:02', '6:31:56', '6:03:18', '5:46:12', '8:26:00', '6:24:27', '5:23:16', '7:12:57', '5:32:07', '5:32:07', '7:09:15', '7:06:12', '6:46:53', '6:28:47', '5:22:24', '7:37:17', '7:21:38', '6:46:46', '6:40:30', '6:16:03', '7:09:29']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't think about the API request. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data by doing the same API call the web page does.

See below

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://my3.raceresult.com/RRPublish/data/list.php?eventid=162106&key=fc9013ff4607be8febcb87f3390c2b4b&listname=Result+Lists%7C1+Classement+L-L&page=results&contest=1&r=all&l=0')
if r.status_code == 200:
  print(r.json())
else:
  print(f'Oops. Status code is {r.status_code}')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! From the json I can move forward!